# Python 2.7 - prime number generator, can't figure out what is wrong with my program

Tags: python, python-2.7, primes

noob programmer here. I am trying to build a small program in 2.7 which generates a prime number, asks the user to continue or not, and then continues generating primes until the user tells it to stop. Unfortunately my program isn't outputting anything at all, and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

First, the part which checks for primes. I know that this part is functioning properly, because the exact same code works properly for my prime factor finder.

```
def isprime(num): #this checks the numbers to see if they're prime
    prime = True
    for i in range(2,num):
        if num/i == (num*1.0)/i:
            prime = False
            return False
            break
        else:
            prime = True
    if prime == True:
        return True
```

And second, the part which iterates through all the numbers, prints result, and asks to continue or not. The error must be in here somewhere:

```
def primegen():
    n = 1
    while True:
        if isprime(n) == True:
            print n
            cont = raw_input("continue? Enter Y/N")
            if cont == 'N':
                break
            n+=1

primegen()
```

Comment: Well, what if `isprime(n)` returns false? What happens then?

Comment: `n+=1` is at the wrong indent level.

Comment: I think the line `n += 1` has wrong indentation. It is only called if `isprime` returns true

Comment: @Phylogenesis and UnholySheep seem to have solutions. Make them full-fledged answers so we can answer this question!

Comment: @fond42518 The question should just be closed because it's a simple typographical error. This is unlikely to be of any help to anyone else.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help; it was really that simple of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

`n` should be incremented unconditionally. If it isn't the program gets stuck in an infinite loop the first time it encounters a non-prime.

```
def primegen():
    n = 1
    while True:
        if isprime(n):
            print n
            cont = raw_input("continue? Enter Y/N")
            if cont == 'N':
                break
        n += 1
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect so many answers so quickly. I just made this correction, and that was the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit chaotic, I would rewrite it like this:

```
def isPrime(num):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        return True
    return False

n=1
while True:
    if isPrime(n):
        print n
        cont = raw_input("Do you want to continue? (1,0) ")
        if not bool(int(cont)):
            break
    n += 1
```